# How to execute command when df -h return 98% full

Tags: linux, shell, sh

How to execute command when df -h return 98% full

I have a disk which is by the

```
/dev/sdb1             917G  816G   55G  94% /disk1
```

If its return 98% full, I would like to do the following

```
find . -size +80M -delete
```

How do I do it, I will run the shell script using cron

```
* * * * * sh /root/checkspace.sh
```

Comment: If you're just going to blindly delete files greater than 80M, why wait until the disk is full? Just run that script on a schedule and call it good.

Comment: Does the importance of files reduce when disk reaches 98%? Or is it always like that? Am I the only one bothered about deleting important files?

Comment: To be fair, it would be a lot better and infinitely safer to figure out what the problem files are and handle them specifically--log rotation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `df -h`, pipe the command output to `grep` matching "/dev/sdb1", and process that line by `awk`, checking to see if the numeric portion of column 5 (`$5` in `awk` terms) is larger than or equal to 98. Don't forget to check for the possibility that it's over 98.

Comment: No need for `grep`... Just `if (( $(df -k | awk '$1 == "/dev/sdb1" { print gensub("%", "", 1, $5) }') >= 98 )); then ....`

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule your script, check the disk utilization, and if the utilization is about 98% then delete files.

For scheduling your script you can reference the [Wikipedia Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) entry.

There is an example of using the find command to delete files on the Unix & Linux site: 
["How to delete directories based on `find` output?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89929/112380)

For your test, you'll need [test constructs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#ICOMPARISON1) and [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). Note that you'll use "backticks" for with sh, but for bash the $(...) form has superseded backticks for command substitution.

To get your disk utilization you could use:

```
    df | grep -F "/dev/sdb1" | awk '{print $5}'
```

--That's a functional grep to get your specific disk, awk to pull out the 5th column, and tr with the delete flag to get rid of the percent sign.

And your test might look something like this:

```
 if [ `df | grep -F "/dev/vda1" | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d %` -ge 98 ];
   then echo "Insert your specific cleanup command here.";
 fi
```

There are many ways to tackle the issue of course, but hope that helps!

Comment: Why now `df /dev/sdb1`? Why not `df --output=pcent /dev/sda1`? Why not `df --output=pcent /dev/sda1 | tail -n1`? ;)

Comment: Those are good comments, but using grep allows you to also exclude the header row so that you can more easily get the integer for testing.